# Load body of another html to jQuery and store as javascript var

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I want to do is to read a body content of another html and save it as a var in a javascript function. What I currently have, using jQuery, is `$(id of this document).load(link goes here)`. For example:

`$("#test").load("/form.cgi?A1=?")`

The form only has a body that contains `<body>some value</body>`

`<a id="test">hello</a>` This method works great because I don't have to use DOM at all.

However, I would like to store the data into a javascript variable. So, I think I have half of this done. Could someone shed some light on how to do so?

Ideally, something like:

'function(test)
{

var x = $.load(test);

//manipulate x such as parseInt/parseFloat, etc

}
'
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to change your approach to this:

```
var myVar = '';
$.get('/form.cgi?A1=?', function(data) {
  myVar = data;
});

alert(myVar);
```

It is not possible to access the value of `myVar` outside the callback function because this Ajax call is asynchronous meaning while the page is being loaded, and the callback function has not been called and the value of myVar has not be changed, the `alert` statement executes which is why you get empty data.

To retain this answer, make use of the `myVar` inside the callback function like this:

```
var myVar = '';
var externalVar = '<p>text</p>';
$.get('/form.cgi?A1=?', function(data) {
  myVar = data;
  //use myVar here for whatever purpose you want it for
  var myNewVar = myVar + ' ' + externalVar;
});
```

You can use the value of `myVar` as soon as the callback function is complete which could be 5sec, 30sec etc after the ajax call

```
<input type="button" value="pol" onclick="alert(myVar);" /> //should work
```

For further information see the links I posted in the comments

Comment: Hi codingbiz. I tried this method, however, the response is empty or ''. When I go back to '$("#test").load("/form.cgi?A1=?")' with an element of id="test", it successfully reads the body content of external html and replaces the element of such id.

Comment: I did check, no errors at all. I tried all the posted methods, but none will work. The external html page only has the '<body>value</value>' is this ok?

Comment: those tags are not well-formed

Comment: put an alert in that function. `alert(data) or alert(myVar)`. It worked for me

Comment: it is correct since this method '$("#test").load("/form.cgi?A1=?")' works. This is really weird. If I put alert(myVar) inside the function right after myVar=data;, it displays everything ('<body>correct value</body>'). However, if I place it outside of the $.get, then it displays empty or ''

Comment: this link should explain why http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754819/how-can-i-access-variables-outside-of-current-scope-in-javascript

Comment: also check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806357/synchronous-get-request-with-javascript-jquery. Check @A.M.K answer

Comment: oh man...for some weird reason, I cleared the browser cache...and this peice of code works. However, it displays the entire content (<body>value</body>). I only need the value. Could you help me wrap this up codingbiz?

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = $("#test").load("/form.cgi?A1=?").html();
```

This should do it if you want the content of the html file as it is.

Comment: Hi Alex, thank you for your answer. However, I just want to load the body content of the other html into a javascript variable. The body content contains a one word string/int like Hi or 123. The problem is that if #test doesn't exist as an id of an element on the current document, then it will not be executed. Is there something like var x = $.load("/form.cgi?A1=?")?

Answer (score 0):

`.load()` is short for `$.ajax()`, so, you can just use a normal Ajax request like so:

jQuery:

```
var result;
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/form.cgi?A1=?',
    success: function(data) {
        result = data;
    },
    async: false
    // async to false so that we don't access an empty variable before the request is finished
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/wHXrM/

Answer (score 0):

Building on what codingbiz provided, this is what I currently have. It's not pretty, but it sure does the trick:

```
$.get( /form.cgi?A1=?, function(data){
    document.getElementById("value").innerHTML = data;
    var y = parseFloat(document.getElementById("value").innerHTML);
    alert(y);
});
```

The reason why I used `document.getElementById("value").innerHTML` is to remove the `<body>` tag that surrounds the desired value (i.e `<body>value</body>`). This is the only way I know so far on how to parseInt/parseFloat properly. If I don't do this, then it return NaN due to the body tag. If you have a better way, do let me know. Thanks